# Getting a HTTP 401/400 when requesting users for a domain in Google Apps Provisioning API

Tags: google-provisioning-api

We have an app that is integrated with Google Apps domains, which allows domain admins to provision users in their Google Apps Domain in our web app on a nightly basis.

Previously I noticed that in cases where the admin revoked access to our app in the cpanel for the domain we would get a HTTP 403 or 401 sometimes, I kinda found this out via some manual testing on my own personal test domain. However, last week we started seeing HTTP 400s even though the request was correctly formed (GET request url and params).

I have two questions

1. Anyone know where in the Provisioning API docs is there info on the various possible HTTP response codes that I can expect.
2. Anyone else see the surge in HTTP 400s lately, due to some undocumented API update ?

UPDATE: The response body for the call is

```
<HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FFFFFF\" TEXT=\"#000000\"> <H1>Bad Request</H1> <H2>Error 400</H2> </BODY> </HTML>
```

UPDATE2: This is the request URL I'm using

```
"https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/#{domain}/user/2.0?alt=json"
```

Comment: 1. Not exactly the full HTTP response code, but Provisioning API is a GDATA api and use the same error response code (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/reference#GDATA_error_codes)

Comment: Emily Lam, I'm using the JSON format for my api calls, and the response body for the calls doesn't refer to any specific GDATA api response codes. I'll update the response body in the question.

Comment: Hey Archit, can you post the HTTP request body since the response body said bad request? I will try to reproduce on my own test domain and see if it provide the same response.  Make sure you get rid of the domain info and such for privacy reason.

Comment: Emily Lam, I've updated the original question with an update which includes the HTTP Response body.

Comment: Hey Archit, without knowing what the request you made (code snippet or even just HTTP protocol), it is hard to tell why it results in 400 error.  If you can update your question with the request you made specifically, it will help me to see what's going on.

Comment: Hey Emily, I'm pretty sure the URL is well formed and correct because the same code snippet and request URL works for other domains that are being used with app. Either way I want to re-iterate that I'm not merely looking for a resolution to the problem (which is explainable if the domain is not registered with google any more), but I'm also trying to find a central location for documentation on error codes (HTTP or otherwise).